# Call <body onload="function()"> in javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've called two functions in my HTML

`<body onload="myFunction()" onmousemove="myFunction1()">`

I want to execute these two functions from a `javascript` file and call this file in my `HTML` like

`<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/functions.js"></script>`

i.e. both the functions will be called from the javascript file, not from html.

I have tried

`window.addEventListener('load', myFunction());
 window.addEventListener('onmousemove', myFunction1());`

or

```
$(window).load(function () {
    myFunction(); 
});
$(window).onmousemove(function () {
    myFunction1(); 
});
```

but failed.

What should I do ?

**DETAILS**

I have a javascript file where some functions are there.

`script.js`

```
function myFunction() {
     alert("This is my function");
}

function myFunction1() {
     alert("This is my second function");
}
```

I called these functions in my html body tag

`<body onload="myFunction()" onmousemove="myFunction1()">`

Now I want to call these two functions from my `script.js` like

```
window.addEventListener('load', myFunction());
 window.addEventListener('onmousemove', myFunction1());
```

what should I do ?

I think you have understood my requirement.

Comment: can you show us using fiddle ?

Comment: `window.addEventListener('load', myFunction());` should be `window.addEventListener('load', myFunction);`

Comment: Hackto has given an aswer that should work. Also the $(window)... notation requires jQuery.

Comment: @Hacketo I have tried `window.addEventListener('load', myFunction)` also, but didn't get the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should read like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load'      , myFunction  );
window.addEventListener('mousemove' , myFunction1 );
```

But if it still does not work for you, Try this:

```
window.onload      = myFunction  ;
window.onmousemove = myFunction1 ;
```

Check this: [onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) and this: [onmousemove](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousemove.asp)

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```js
function number1(){
    document.querySelector("#info").innerHTML = "LOAD";
  }
  
  function number2(){
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;

   document.querySelector("#info").innerHTML = "MouseMove: ( x:"+x+" , y:"+y+") ";
  }
  
    window.onload = function(){
   number1()
   }
    
   window.onmousemove = function(){
   number2()
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="info">waiting</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think You should verify that your (.js) file is loaded with the page or not?
Because i have tried both the example and both r working
 `window.addEventListener('load', myFunction);` and `window.addEventListener('load', myFunction());`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Page is loaded");
}
window.addEventListener('load', myFunction);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        alert("Page is loaded");
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', myFunction());
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The only reason the 2nd one is working, is that `myFunction()` is being called as part of the call to `addEventListener`... it's not happening **because** the event is being called.  It is wrong to state that the 2nd way of doing it is correct